# how we check one array element and put in another array row wise in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Below is my **Rules Array**
in this array outlook,temp.
**For exapample Outlook contain values sunny,overcase and rainy and also have yes or no values.**

```
$Rules = Array
(
[Outlook] => Array
    (
        [Sunny] => Array
            (
                [No] => 2
            )

        [Overcast ] => Array
            (
                [Yes] => 1
            )

        [Rainy] => Array
            (
                [Yes] => 1
            )

    )

[Temp] => Array
    (
        [Hot] => Array
            (
                [No] => 2
                [Yes] => 1
            )

        [Mild] => Array
            (
                [Yes] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

**and below is my $filling array and i want to fill the values of yes and no according to the rules array.**
first i pick the **all first element row wise**
example we pick outlook -> sunny , temp -> hot and then check in the above array by heading and count yes no values and which value of yes or no greater then we put in play field respectively.

```
$filling = Array
(
[Outlook] => Array
    (

        [0] => Sunny
        [1] => Sunny
        [2] => Overcast 
        [3] => Rainy
    )

[Temp] => Array
    (

        [0] => Hot
        [1] => Hot
        [2] => Hot
        [3] => Mild
    )
 [play] => Array
    (

        [0] =>
        [1] =>
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    )
)
```

**Example:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChrlB.png)

Comment: whats wrong with `sunny => true`? I think you're making it way more complicated than you need to.

Comment: Sir sunny contain the values of yes and no

Comment: what you have tried ?? edit the question and paste your code.... dear @shan

Comment: Sir i am new in php i have tried just

Comment: $rowarray = array();
foreach($Rules as $countVk => $countV){
   
   foreach($Rules as $countVk => $countV){

for($i=0; $<=$countVk; $i++){
$rowarray[$countVk][$i];
}
   

      }

     }

Comment: @shan, checkout the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36591918/how-we-check-one-array-element-and-put-in-another-array-row-wise-in-php/36592612#36592612)

Comment: Sir i checked but i wish to fill the Yes ,No values of Play field in the filling array.

Comment: give the example in your question.

Comment: sir please check the image as an example

Comment: update your question, not my answer.

Comment: @shan, fillup your `Play` field with values and add the conditions.

Comment: Sir i am new in php its problem

Answer (score 1):

You can check by running [online scripts](https://3v4l.org/BmBmn)

**Your Array:**

```
$Rules = array(
    "Outlook" => array("Sunny" => array("No" => 2),
                       "Overcast" => array("Yes" => 1),
                       "Rainy" => array("Yes" => 1)
                ),
    "Temp" => array("Hot" => array("No" => 2, "Yes" => 1),
                   "Mild" => array("Yes" => 1)
                )

);
```

**New array with condition**

```
$filling = array();
$fill_play = array();

foreach($Rules as $key => $value){
    $in = 0;
    $in_play = 0;
    foreach($value as $keys => $values){
        $key_value = array_keys($values);
        for($j = 0; $j < count($key_value); $j++){
            for($i = 0; $i < $values[$key_value[$j]]; $i++){
                $fill_play[$key][$in_play++] = $key_value[$j];
                $filling[$key][$in++] = $keys;
            }
        }
    }       
}
$yes_no = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    $yes_no[$i] = 0;

foreach($fill_play as $key => $value){
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
        if($value[$i] == 'No')
            $yes_no[$i] -= 1;
        else
            $yes_no[$i] += 1;
    }       
}

foreach($yes_no as $key => $value){
    if($value >= 0)
        $filling['Play'][$key] = 'Yes';
    else
        $filling['Play'][$key] = 'No';
}
```

**Output**

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($filling);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [Outlook] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sunny
            [1] => Sunny
            [2] => Overcast
            [3] => Rainy
        )

    [Temp] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hot
            [1] => Hot
            [2] => Hot
            [3] => Mild
        )

    [Play] => Array
        (
            [0] => No
            [1] => No
            [2] => Yes
            [3] => Yes
        )

)
```

Comment: But sir i wish to fill the Play fields values of Yes and No . According to Rules Array

Comment: depending on what? The `Rules` array are many values?? How much the `Play` fields?